# Store data in ES and not on MongoDB using mongoosastic

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am trying to build a search engine project using `mongoosastic` and was wondering if there was a way to store specific data fields only on `elasticsearch` and not on `MongoDB` as this would basically make it duplication of data.

For example we can use the `es_indexed` to make sure `elasticsearch` indexes the data and stores it to `MongoDB` but is there something similar which can make sure `elasticsearch` indexes the data but `MongoDb` does *not* store it.

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose')
  , mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic')
  , Schema       = mongoose.Schema

var User = new Schema({
    name: {type:String, es_indexed:true}
  , email: String
  , city: String
  , comments: {type:[Comment], es_indexed:true}
})

User.plugin(mongoosastic)
```

I was checking the same with `mongoose` as well but it wasn't working.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: I would not do that - ElasticSearch is focused on search and search performance; the guarantees it offers regarding correctness and robustness are weaker than other DB systems. Specifically, it's possible to lose data. Duplicating data is fine: one DB is your reference (MongoDB), and in ElasticSearch you index the data for the purpose of search.

Comment: @AdrienF

I am using `elasticsearch` for searching purposes only. I'm sending in the `_id` and keys which needs to be searched only to the `ES Cluster` while all the needed data like passwords and other information is held in `MongoDB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `select: false` will insert the data only to `elasticsearch` and not `mongodb`

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose')
  , mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic')
  , Schema       = mongoose.Schema

var User = new Schema({
    name: {type:String, es_indexed:true}
  , email: String
  , city: String
  , comments: {type:[Comment], es_indexed:true, select: false}
})

User.plugin(mongoosastic)
```